# Logstash ElasticSearch IOException :

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to use Logstash and ElasticSearch for the first time and I get some troubles doing so.

ES version : 1.7.2 (also tried with 2.0.0 beta2 for the same result).
Logstash version : 1.5.4

The context : I'm using the logstash [JDBC plugin](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin) and when trying to index a table content in ES, I have an exception :

```
    [2015-09-20 13:08:42,238][WARN ][http.netty               ] [Willie Lumpkin] Caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [id: 0x729e1f0d, /127.0.0.1:64177 => /127.0.0.1:9200]
java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Logstash conf file is as follow :

```
input {
    jdbc {
        # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Dell"
        # The user we wish to execute our statement as
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        # The password
        jdbc_password => "****"
        # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
        jdbc_driver_library => "postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar"
        # The name of the driver class for Postgresql
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        # our query
        statement => "SELECT * from products"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {
        protocol => http
        index => "products"
        document_type => "product"
        document_id => "%{uid}"
        host => "127.0.0.1"
    }
}
```

If I run a

```
curl localhost:9200/_cluster/health/?pretty
```

before indexing, the cluster status is green. After trying to index, it turns yellow.

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 10,
  "active_shards" : 10,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 10,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
}
```

The stdout output for Logstash works fine.

Thanks for your help.

PS : if I run any command on Logstash, it works but I get the following message :

```
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
```

Comment: The `io/console` message is a windows bug. Please see the [github issue](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1614) for more information. Since `stdout` works, your problem looks like an ES issue. I would recommend you to start with a new `elasticsearch.yml` config. Can you add documents manually?

Comment: Hi, concerning the elasticsearch.yml, mine was blank (default values everywhere). I created a VM with Linux Mint on it. I copied ES and Logstash folders on this VM and tried to run it. It worked ! My next concern is to have Kibana running with my datas. Thanks for your help.